# Python how to read() and convert to __int__

Tags: python, text

I have a text file that contains the XP of the player in it.
Every time the game starts:

```
if os.path.getsize("game_data.txt") != 0:
    with open("game_data.txt"), "r") as f:
        XP = f.readline()
else:
     XP = 0
```

, so that the XP of the player sets to the only item in the file. And at the end of the file (around `pygame.quit()`) it has this code:

```
with open("game_data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(XP))
```

But whenever I try to do `XP += (some number)` in my code, I get an error saying that `XP` is a string (because what I .read() is always a string) so I cannot use += with a number. Is there a way to explicitly convert what you `.read()` to `__int__`?

Comment: `XP = int(f.readline())`

Comment: Oh my... Thanks it was easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```py
if os.path.getsize("game_data.txt") != 0:
    with open("game_data.txt"), "r") as f:
        XP = int(float(f.readline()))
else:
     XP = 0
```